# :qMacOS: Error: Failed to initialize log. No logging is enabled: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/snowsql_rt.log_bootstrap'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have downloaded and installed SnowSQL onto my Mac.

After entering the following command

```sh
snowsql -a zx12334 -u someone
```

I am getting the following error

> Failed to initialize log. No logging is enabled: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/snowsql_rt.log_bootstrap'

Any idea how I could fix it?

In my config file, I have enabled `log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log`.
It does so automatically by installer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your **config** file (~/.snowsql) you need to modify this line:

```
log_file = ../snowsql_rt.log
```

to this:

```
log_file = ~/.snowsql/snowsql_rt.log
```

Comment: Thank you Sergiu! One step closer! For some reason, it took out that Errno 13, but now it says, " [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/csamanie/.snowsql/1.2.9/snowsql' "
Any Ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you installed the MAC version? Run **file /Users/csamanie/.snowsql/1.2.9/snowsql** and provide output.

Comment: Also maybe try to reinstall using version 1.2.10 (remove first 1.2.9 by deleting **rm -rf ~/.snowsql/1.2.9**

Comment: After running the file: "/Users/csamanie/.snowsql/1.2.9/snowsql: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=some-long-string, stripped"

Comment: I was able to get rid of that error by uninstalling and reinstalling 2.10. After running snowsql -a .<a-name> -u <username> I got "Installing version: 1.2.10  [####################################]  100%          
Unsupported option is found: SNOWSQL_DOWNLOAD_DIR"

Comment: I got it working! Thank you so much Sergiu for your help!