# Windows login error in snowsql with Permission denied error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

while logging into snowsql getting below error in windows *86_64

Failed to initialize log. No logging is enabled: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\snowsql_rt.log_bootstrap'
Failed to initialize log. No logging is enabled: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\snowsql_rt.log'

Please advise

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717416/qmacos-error-failed-to-initialize-log-no-logging-is-enabled-errno-13-perm/64717779#64717779)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the config file that is installed in .snowsql, you can edit this file in notepad, look for the log_file entry and you can update this to something like C:\Temp<file_name> The same can be done for the log_bootstrap_file entry too if you need.